# 3rd axis possible in Oracle Business Inteligence?

Tags: obiee

I have to show 3 dimensions in OBIEE. Z axis is period(2001 till 2014), X axis is age, Y axis is population for a city. I dig into menus but I think it is not possible in OBIEE. Am I right?

Note: I am trying to make a chart like below...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPbcy.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully, I am pretty sure that you are correct – that can't be done with the built-in charts. But that's definitely a [good](http://peltiertech.com/the-perils-of-being-in-3d/) [thing](http://www.perceptualedge.com/example3.php).

A line chart with a series for each age group (period on x, population on y) would probably be far better, so long as you only have about 5 or fewer age bands.

Comment: I could not agree more... please, please, please stay away from 3D charts, and even color gradients, as they simply detract from the data and information at hand.